# How to make javascript variables unique inside an asp.net core foreach?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've something like the following in a razor page:

```
@foreach (var item in list)
        {
            <h3 id="time-@item.id"></h3> <!--The id is unique because of the addition of the list item's ID-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
                let currentDateTime-@item.id = new Date(Date.now());
                $('#time-@item.id').html(currentDateTime-@item.id) // Item.id displays like text and doesn't apply to the variable itself.
                function getdone-@item.id(){ // Functions too
                }
            </script>
        }
```

I need to make those variables/function/IDs unique for each item of the list.

Comment: Don't put your JavaScript in a Razor loop. Structure it in a way that you only have a single instance of those functions, and then have the functions operate on different elements by Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `item.id` in parentheses: `@(item.id)`

```
@foreach (var item in list)
{
    <h3 id="time-@item.id"></h3>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let currentDateTime-@(item.id) = new Date(Date.now());
        $('#time-@(item.id)').html(currentDateTime-@(item.id));
        function getdone-@(item.id)(){
        }
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image: descr]

https://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/